# drawing navigation arrow shape using css

Tags: html, css, draw, shapes, css-shapes

I'm trying to draw a navigation arrow using css only, I wrote this code

```
<span class="outer">
   <span class="inner"></span>
</span>
```

with the style

```
.outer {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-radius: 30px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.inner {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 15px 10px 0;
    border-color: transparent #000 transparent transparent;
    position: absolute;
    right: 35%;
    top: 24%;
}
```

but i want the inner triangle be like this <, not as play button. i shared my code on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lqh3zLmj/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a pseudo element to get this sort of shape.

The only drawback being you would need to know the `top` and `left` values; they aren't relative to the size of `.inner`.

```css
.outer {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    border-radius: 30px;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
.inner {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 15px 10px 0;
    border-color: transparent #000 transparent transparent;
    position: absolute;
    right: 35%;
    top: 24%;
}

.inner:after{
    content:'';
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 15px 10px 0;
    border-color: transparent #FFF transparent transparent;
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: -10px;    
}
```

```html
<span class="outer">
    <span class="inner"></span>
</span>
```

This simply places the same sized arrow on top of `.inner`, but nudged over a few pixels. Increase the `left` style to make the arrow 'thicker'.

Comment: Or just use the `less than` symbol `<`...works just as well and is simpler CSS markup.

Comment: @Paulie_D I would have thought that option would go without saying. Especially since the OP used it in the question

Comment: You'd think so...but I meant in your `content` property...then you can style it with font properties...no need for borders.